# How to re run a function changing a variable when the conditions are met in R?

Tags: r

I have a function with an structure like this:

```
 function(x, y, z, n = 3){
  
  test = #funky fit with the input data
  
  other = #more metrics 
  
    #conditions to evaluate the model
  if (condition1 = TRUE){ #condition based on other or test
    #rerun function with n = 2
  } else if (condition2 = TRUE) {#condition based on other or test
    #rerun function with n = 1
  } else {
    #save the output
  }
    
}
```

I'm wondering how can I re run the function when condition 1 or 2 are met changing `n` to 2 or 1 respectively. I am aware of `while` but I'm not sure how to implement it on this situation.

Comment: why not set the n according to your condition? `if (condition1 = TRUE){n=2...}`

Comment: The values to evaluate the condition are the result of the first run of the function so that won't work on this case

Comment: Do you know what recursion is?

Comment: Tests of logical equality are done with “==“, not “=“. And if it’s really a logical expression then that step isn’t even necessary when one of the arguments is TRUE. For recursion you should lol at the documentation and examples at ?Recall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use recursion?

```r
recurse = function(x, y, z, n = 3){
  test = #funky fit with the input data
  other = #more metrics 
  
  if (condition1){
    recurse(x, y, z, n = 2)
  } else if (condition2) {
    recurse(x, y, z, n = 1)
  } else {
    # Choose the return value here
    other
  }
}
```

Comment: But make sure to set the conditions in such a way that you avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: Indeed, but from the OP it seems like this will only recurse once at most